# Why would setting the prompt in .bashrc not actually affect the prompt?

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to set my shell prompt by inserting the following line into `.bashrc` in my home directory:

```
export PS1="\[\e[01;36m\][\u]\[\e[0m\] \[\e[01;37m\]\W\[\e[0m\] $ "
```

I save this file and re-open bash, but it doesn't change. When I issue the command `echo $PS1`, the console shows

```
\h:\w$
```

which is the default prompt. I looked around `.bashrc` and do not see the `PS1` environment variable being set anywhere except the line that I inserted shown above.

This works on my local machine, but with my account on a remote server it won't stick. How do I make the custom prompt go into effect?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you are using bash? Try `echo $SHELL`.

Comment: Yes. On startup, issuing `echo $SHELL` returns `/bin/bash`

Comment: Is it possible your .bashrc is being called by .bash_profile or .profile (or that .bashrc is calling them), and so something is overriding them later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is the difference between login and interactive shells. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/438170/85695) for a summary.

`~/.bashrc` is only read when starting an **interactive** (non-login) shell. When you `ssh`into a remote machine, you are running a **login** shell so `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` or `~/.profile` (in that order) are read instead. You can check this by running `bash` after loging on to the remote server, that will start an interactive shell, `~/.bashrc` will be read and your modified prompt will appear.

To change the prompt that appears when you `ssh`, set `$PS1` in `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PS1="\[\e[01;36m\][\u]\[\e[0m\] \[\e[01;37m\]\W\[\e[0m\] $ "
```

Alternatively, you could call `~/.bashrc` from `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile`:

```
if [ "$BASH" ]; then
  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
  fi
fi
```

The `if [ "$BASH" ]; then` is useful when using `~/.profile` since it will be read by non-bash shells.

Comment: I've moved the `export` statement into `.profile`, but it still doesn't work. I didn't have a `.bash_profile` file, so I created one and stuck the statement in there, but to no avail. 

I also tried to run an interactive shell after logging in, but it does not set `PS1` either. Do you have any ideas as to what's going on?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @EvanW does it work if you run the export command directly from the terminal?

Comment: Ah -- I figured it out. At the end of my `.profile` file, a shell script was called that modified `PS1` again. I moved my `export` statement to after the `source` statement calling the script and it works fine. Thank you!