# Where a bash variable (proxy) is defined

Tags: shell, proxy, environment-variables

I have a problem with `wget` and I've discover that my proxy settings is wrong:

```
$ env | grep "proxy"
http_proxy=http://213.181.73.145:80
https_proxy=http://213.181.73.145:80
```

So, when I try to download something with `wget`, it fails trying to connect to the proxy, and not trying to connect to the web resource that I need to download.

But in superuser mode all is correct:

```
$ sudo su
$ env | grep "proxy"
$
```

(empty output, no proxy)

I want to know where this variables are settings, and I found a lots of problems. I added the next line to the beginning of my `/etc/profile`:

```
env | grep "proxy"
echo "Hello"
```

And for me surprise, both variables are settings with that same values before any configuration file is loaded (/etc/bashrc, ~/.bashrc, etc):

```
(new terminal)
http_proxy=http://213.181.73.145:80
https_proxy=http://213.181.73.145:80
Hello
$
```

Moreover, I work with `guake`. So, I tried the same with a common terminal, and for me surprise, (I think) the file `/etc/profile` isn't loaded, since I don't see nor the proxy lines but neither the `echo "Hello"` message.

So, I would like to know how is possible that `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` are defined before loading `/etc/profile` and why I don't see the "Hello" message when I open a common terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The message is not displayed when you open a "normal" terminal because `/etc/profile` is only read for login shells, a "normal" terminal starts an interactive, non-login shell. See my answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/563887/151431) for more information.

Now, I don't know where your `http_proxy` is set. Depending on what exactly your setup is, it could be in various places. Try this:

```
grep http_proxy /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_login ~/.profile ~/bash_profile
```

The variable should be set in one of those files.

Answer (score 0):

Some file that is run on shell startup is setting the environment variables, such as ~/.bashrc , ~/.bash_profile, or /etc/bash.bashrc

You don't have to change any file to take off the proxy variable, though! All you have to do is use the 'unset' command!

```
$ unset http_proxy
$ unset https_proxy
```

Now those environment variables are gone! If you can't track down where they are set, you can add that to the end of your ~/.bashrc, and unset them for every shell. If you test it out again:

```
$ env | grep proxy
[nothing]
```

You'll see they've gone!

Comment: But, the key of the question is that this variable is set before any configuration file is loaded. The question is where can a variable be setted before /etc/profile.